# Updating Records with a dynamically generated form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, forms

Hello everyone first time comment here so please forgive my poor formatting, I am currently working on a project and have hit a serious wall. Before I show the code please read what I am aiming for here, it is rather complex.

So the form that creates the data that I am trying to update in MySQL is dynamically generated, so users can add or remove input fields as needed. So there can be any number of fields to update. The initial population of the table works just fine but here is were it gets interesting.

The page I am having trouble with is the page where users review the data that was submitted, and can make changes as they see fit.

So, the data I am using, just for the sake of putting names to faces, are requirements that must be met in order to qualify for an evaluation. There can be any number of these. So I query and return all of the requirements tied to the evaluation, and then loop through them and echo input fields with the values the user originally submitted.

Bellow you can see what I am talking about, so what I need to do is create an array of form elements that I can loop through. I have the Primary Key of the requirment that needs to be updated under the $Baseline_Requirements_ID PHP variable in a hidden input field (text field in code below for testing) so I can target the correct record in the table and update it with the content in text area.

So ultimately, I feel I have to have the names of the fields be arrays so I can target them, get the length of the array, and then update the records within that loop. Only issue is I can not figure out how to generate the array.

Thank you in advance, Zach

```
<form id="requirments" name="requirments" method="post" action="">
    <?php
        $Baseline_Requirements = array();
        $Baseline_Requirements_ID = array();
        $bas_count = 1;
        mysql_data_seek($BaselineRequirments, 0);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($BaselineRequirments))
        {
            $Baseline_Requirments[] = $row['Requirement'];
            $Baseline_Requirements_ID[] = $row['Baseline_Requirement_ID'];
        }
        $Req_index = 0;
        foreach ($Baseline_Requirments as $value)
        {
            echo "<textarea name='requirment[]'
                    id='requirment$count' cols='45' rows='5'>";
            echo $value;
            echo "</textarea>";
            echo "<input name='Baseline_Requirement_ID[]' type='text'
                    value='$Baseline_Requirements_ID[$Req_index]'>";
            $bas_count = $bas_count +1;
            $Req_index = $Req_index +1;

        }
```

Comment: I apologize for commenting on my own post here, just wanted to clarify exactly what I am aiming for. I need to have the Input fields I am echoing in the loop have arrays for names. That way I can loop through each input field and update the correlating record in the database.

Comment: Hi, well thought out question, but perhaps not all the context is relevant. Try searching for key terms relevant to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Patrick, I am currently research heavily  as we speak! And I noticed that a little with the question, I have been reading questions on stack overflow for so many years now, never made a post but the one thing I think they could use is some in-depth explanation of the process and implementation of what there questions relate to so users looking at the resolution better understand exactly what is happening. But I wouldn't know much compared to an experienced user. I'll change it up next time. Thanks again!

Comment: this might help http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php#87650

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, what array are you trying to generate? The array of column/field names? Could you not also include a hidden field that holds the index of the field in the order you retrieve it from the database table? Or even use the index as say, field numbering?